# Firestore update from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I have a dictionary that contains a number of keys and values that should be applied to a document. Pseudocode to explain what I am trying to do:

```
doc_ref.update({*[k: v for k,v in dict],
                }, firestore.CreateIfMissingOption(True))
```

or

```
doc_ref.update({from_dict(dict),
                }, firestore.CreateIfMissingOption(True))
```

What is the most pythonic way to update a document from an existing dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I settled on.

```
batch = db.batch()
...
for k in dict:
    batch.update(doc_ref, {k: dict[k]}, firestore.CreateIfMissingOption(True))
batch.commit()
```